# My program crashes on the second click in listview

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bufferedreader

Solved ;)
I know that its bat idea but i used Globals .class and now it works ;)
Now it works ;) hurahhh

Thank you guys

Primary question

When i click on 'ListView' item second time an error occurs and the app closes.

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong because it works with each element perfectly for the first time, whereas the second time it dont works even the ListView item that was clicked at first (without any problem) is clicked again.

```
    package com.klemenjezakon.koceSLO;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class KocaInter extends ListActivity {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String temp;
    InputStreamReader reader;
    int n = 2;
    koca[] koce = new koca[n];
    ArrayList<String> kocee = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> podatek = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, kocee));

        inicjalizacijaKoc();

    }

    private void inicjalizacijaKoc() {

        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("s_koce.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try {
                kocee.add("" + br.readLine());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);


        int a = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            a=R.drawable.slika0000;
            break;
        case 1:
            a=R.drawable.slika0001;
            break;
            default:
            a=R.drawable.slika0000;

        }

        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("koce_podatki.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        for(int i=-1;i<position;i++){
        try {
            temp = "" + br.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] nov = temp.split("\\|");

        for(int i=0;i<23;i++){
            podatek.add(""+nov[i]);
        }
        temp=""+sb.append(a);

        podatek.set(0,temp);

        Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        in.putExtra("array", podatek);

        startActivity(in);

        podatek.clear();

    }

}
```

And main activity:

```
package com.klemenjezakon.koceSLO;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ImageView slika;
        ArrayList<String> podatki;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                podatki = extras.getStringArrayList("array");
            }

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;

            setContentView(R.layout.koca);

            int n=-1;

            int pic=++n;

            TextView ime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ime);
            ime.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView visina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.visina);
            visina.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView odprt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odprt);
            odprt.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView gorPredel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gorPredel);
            gorPredel.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView PD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PD);
            PD.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView Oskrbnik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Oskrbnik);
            Oskrbnik.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tel);
            tel.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView GSM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GSM);
            GSM.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView telPD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TelPD);
            telPD.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView mail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mail);
            mail.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView web = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web);
            web.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView naslov = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.naslov);
            naslov.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView kat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kat);
            kat.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView lez = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lez);
            lez.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView stJed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stJed);
            stJed.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView cen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cen);
            cen.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView dostop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dostop);
            dostop.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView opis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opis);
            opis.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView razg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.razg);
            razg.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView pTure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pTure);
            pTure.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView bKoce = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bKoce);
            bKoce.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));
            TextView vzponi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vzponi);
            vzponi.setText("" + (podatki.get(++n).toString()));

            Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    Integer.parseInt(podatki.get(pic)));
            ImageView slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);
            slika.setImageBitmap(foto);

            slika.setMinimumWidth(width);
            slika.setMaxWidth(width);



        }
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                // do something on back.
                finish();
                return true;
            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

    }
```

Thank you ;)

Logcat:
http://www.file.si/pfiles/273442/Untitled.png

Comment: post your stacktrace please

Comment: what does your logcat say?

Comment: You should really check the length of the ¨nov¨ (from the split())

Comment: http://www.file.si/public/view/full/273442

Comment: You got exception in MainActivity not in this ListActivity please append the code in question of MainActivity class

Comment: but first code is luncher...

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    Integer.parseInt(podatki.get(pic)));
```

here you getting error I thing as per the error message its too vary value so its Long not an Int value. Check in onCreate() in MainActivity

**Edited**

In item on click you are selecting Resource and store in **a** object this object was appending in **sb** object now what happen every time you click it will append it.

```
temp=""+sb.append(a); // here appended a (selected resource value)
```

you need to clear every time this value or you can pass this in another extra value in intent object

```
in.putExtra("resourceId", a);
```

then on `MainActivity` not need to parse and typecasting problem just getting in int value and directly used in `BitmapFactory`, like this way

```
Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),extras.getInt("resourceId"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                Integer.parseInt(podatki.get(pic)));
```

Is the line where its erroring, more specifically:

```
Integer.parseInt(podatki.get(pic))
```

According to the logcat it looks like `podatki.get(pic)` is returning a string which is too long to be converted into an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at this line in your code.

```
 Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    Integer.parseInt(podatki.get(pic)));
```

Change it as below

```
 Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.yourpic);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @KlemenKogovšek Then you can't decodeResource, you have decodeFile which you need to store in SDcard if they are dynamically downloaded or else you have to store them in the assets and decode them as file. But decodeResource() with dynamic values is not possible.

Comment: @KlemenKogovšek I am not asking you to change the data type to long, I am saying to you to store the image files in sdcard or else in assets folder of your project and then decode them as file using decodeFile() instead of decodeResource(). decodeResource() is used only for decoding resources which have static final reference. home you understood.

Comment: It has wirked before i change from reading from ram to reading from file

Comment: I can't help you sorry. but as far as I know decode resource with the dynamic values is not possible.

Comment: I know that its bat idea but i used Globals .class and now it works ;)